# ActiveRecord Includes n+1 issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using the Bullet gem to assist me in finding my n + 1 errors for my ActiveRecord queries.  I currently am passing in:

@user = User.includes(:routines => {:lifts => [:exercise, :infos]}).find(current_user.id)

To me this means I am loading the current user, his routines, those routines' lifts, and those lifts' exercise and infos (which are sets).

1. Is my assumption true?
2. The Bullet gem is giving me two errors in which it is claiming I need to:
   Lift => [:routine] so it says add ".include => [:routine]"
   AND
   Lift => [:infos] so it says add ".include => [:infos]"

Would somebody be able to explain this to me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely are on the right path.  I highly recommend brushing up on this via [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Your setup supports pre-loading when you access data like this:

```
routines = @user.routines
lifts = @user.routines.map(&:lifts)
```

Can you please describe how you are attempting to access this data?  It appears that you may be trying to access routine via:

```
lift.routine
```

How are you accessing `lift`?

You might want to make sure that you use `:inverse_of` when specifying your associations.
Does `Routine` have many `:lifts`?

Comment: My current relationships are as follows: A user has many routines, a routine has many lifts, a lift belongs to an exercise and has many infos(sets).  I am trying to eager load all of those in one because I am displaying all the routines/lifts/exercise names/infos(sets) on a single page.

Comment: An exercise has many lifts and a lift belongs to a single exercise. This way we only have one instant of 'squat' in the exercise table and multiple lifts who's exercise name is 'squat'.